# Multi dimensional array with varying size

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

I want to make a 2D array "data" with the following dimensions: data(T,N)
T is a constant and N I dont know anything about to begin with. Is it possible to do something like this in fortran

```
      do i = 1, T
           check a few flags
           if (all flags ok) 
             c = c+ 1
             data(i,c) = some value
           end if
       end do
```

Basically I have no idea about the second dimension. Depending on some flags, if those flags are fine, I want to keep adding more elements to the array.

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry, its a 2D array

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions.   You could make `data` an allocatable array and guess the maximum value for `N`.  As long as you don't excess `N`, you keep adding data items.  If a new item would exceed the array size, you create a temporary array, copy `data` to the temporary array, deallocate `data` and reallocate with a larger dimension.

Another design choice would be to use a linked list. This is more flexible in that the length is indefinite.   You loss "random access" in that the list is chained rather than indexed.  You create an user defined type that contains various data, e.g., scalers, arrays, whatever, and also a pointer.  When you add a list item, the pointer points to that next item.  The is possible in Fortran >=90 since pointers are supported.

I suggest searching the web or reading a book about these data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you wrote is more-or-less how your code really goes, then you assuredly do know one thing: `N` cannot be greater than `T`. You would not have to change your `do`-loop, but you will definitely need to initialize `data` before the loop.